Latex table with complex multirow structure including intermittent lines
I am new to Latex and I know the basic coding, however I would like to create the following complex table (see attachement) in latex and I can't find a way to succeed. I already read some of the threads here discussed and tried multiple solutions like '\multirow' or just leaving empty spaces before the '&' sign, but nothing worked until this point. The most difficult part from my opinion part is to implement the complex line structure in the table. For instance, when I use '\hline' after the row concerning "heart with internal heart chamber structures", it also devides the cell containing "R01: Key organs of phantom", but this is undesired. I hope somebody can help me out with this :) Sorry if my explanation is not entirely clear, I am happy to give extra information if necessary. Thank you in advance!
Kind regards
Marthe

I already tried the following to start with:
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Overview of design requirements and specifications for the US compatible thorax phantom}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{4,5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Requirement} & \textbf{Specification} & \textbf{Absolute requirement} &\textbf{Desire} & \textbf{Nice-to-have} \\
        \hline
        \multirow{6}{*}{R01: Key organs} & Heart with internal heart chamber structures & \centering{X} &  & \\ \cline{2-5}
            & Ribcage & \centering{X} & & \\ \cline{2-5}
            & Sternum & \centering{X} & & \\ \cline{2-5}
            & Surrounding bulk soft tissue & \centering{X} & & \\ \cline{2-5}
            & Intercostal muscle layer & & \centering{X} & \\ \cline{2-5}
            & Skin layer & & & \centering{X} \\ \cline{2-5}
            & Lungs & & & \centering{X} \\
            \hline
            R02: Dimensions of phantom & Real-life scale.
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:Overview_of_design_requirements_and_specifications_for_the_US_compatible_thorax_phantom}
\end{table}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code you have tried so far!

With tabularray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]\centering
\caption{Overview of design requirements and specifications for the US compatible thorax phantom}\label{tab:Overview_of_design_requirements_and_specifications_for_the_US_compatible_thorax_phantom}
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[l,m,3cm]X[l,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
    vlines, hlines,
    row{1}={font=\bfseries},
    measure=vbox,stretch=-1,
    rowsep=4pt,
    }        
    Requirement & Specification & \SetCell{l} {Absolute\\ requirement} & \SetCell{l} Desire & \SetCell{l} Nice-to-have \\
    \SetCell[r=7]{l} R01: Key organs & Heart with internal heart chamber structures & X &  & \\ 
    & Ribcage & X & & \\ 
    & Sternum & X & & \\ 
    & Surrounding bulk soft tissue & X & & \\ 
    & Intercostal muscle layer & & X & \\ 
    & Skin layer & & & X \\ 
    & Lungs & & & X \\
    R02: Dimensions of phantom & {Real-life scale.\\ RDI:}
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item[-] Sternum + part of ribs 1--6 which cover the heart
    \item[-] Depth: few cm below heart ($\sim 13$cm)
    \end{itemize}\\
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}



Here is a way to create that tabular with {NiceTabular} of nicematrix. However, I would recommend a table in the style of booktabs.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Overview of design requirements and specifications for the US compatible thorax phantom}
\begin{NiceTabular}{Xp{4.5cm}ccc}[hvlines]
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
Requirement & Specification & \Block{}{Absolute\\ requirement} & Desire & Nice-to-have \\
\Block[l]{7-1}{R01: Key organs} & Heart with internal heart chamber structures & X &  & \\ 
    & Ribcage & X & & \\ 
    & Sternum & X & & \\ 
    & Surrounding bulk soft tissue & X & & \\ 
    & Intercostal muscle layer & & X & \\ 
    & Skin layer & & & X \\ 
    & Lungs & & & X \\
    R02: Dimensions of phantom & Real-life scale. \newline
    ROI:            
    \setlength{\parskip}{-12pt} % Adjust spacing between text and itemize environment
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{-6pt} % Adjust spacing between items
        \item Sternum
        \item Depth
    \end{itemize} & X &  & \\ 
    R03: Echnographic realism\newline
    -- US Compatible & US properties \newline SOS $\sim$ 1540 m/s & X & & \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\label{tab:Overview_of_design_requirements_and_specifications_for_the_US_compatible_thorax_phantom}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Here's a suggestion for a start how to write the table.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Overview of design requirements and specifications for the US compatible thorax phantom}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{4.5cm}|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \makecell[l]{\textbf{Requirement}\\ {}} & \makecell[l]{\textbf{Specification}\\ {}} & \makecell[l]{\textbf{Absolute}\\ \textbf{requirement}} &\makecell[l]{\textbf{Desire}\\ {}} & \makecell[l]{\textbf{Nice-to-have}\\ {}} \\
        \hline
        \multirow[t]{6}{*}{R01: Key organs} & Heart with internal heart chamber structures & X &  & \\ \cline{2-5}
            & Ribcage & X & & \\ \cline{2-5}
            & Sternum & X & & \\ \cline{2-5}
            & Surrounding bulk soft tissue & X & & \\ \cline{2-5}
            & Intercostal muscle layer & & X & \\ \cline{2-5}
            & Skin layer & & & X \\ \cline{2-5}
            & Lungs & & & X \\
            \hline
            R02: Dimensions of phantom & Real-life scale. \newline
            ROI:            
            \setlength{\parskip}{-12pt} % Adjust spacing between text and itemize environment
            \begin{itemize}
                \setlength{\itemsep}{-6pt} % Adjust spacing between items
                \item Sternum
                \item Depth
            \end{itemize} & X &  & \\ \hline
            R03: Echnographic realism\newline
            -- US Compatible & US properties \newline SOS $\sim$ 1540 m/s & X & & \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:Overview_of_design_requirements_and_specifications_for_the_US_compatible_thorax_phantom}
\end{table}

\end{document}


